# jQuery.maskedInput - Switching input masks dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, mask

I have a text field that requires a mask.  As per the suggestions on other SO threads I am using this jQuery plugin to do this: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/.

I am having a problem with it however.  There 2 different masks that can be applied to my input field.  The decision of which one to use can only be determined after the first 4 characters have been inputed.  So here's what I have:

```
$('#user-input').keyup(function () {
     current_val = $(this).val();
     if (current_val.replace(/\s*$/, "").length == 4){
         mask = determineMask(current_val);
         $(this).unmask();
         $(this).mask(mask);
     }
});
```

When the line "$(this).mask(mask)" fires, all existing input is removed.  Does anyone know how to prevent this package from doing that?  Is there another plugin, library, code snippet, etc that would be better at dong what i am trying to do here?

Comment: Did you manage to do this with masked input plugin ?

Comment: Sadly no.  It wasn't a requirement of my project, just a little bit of UI icing so I abandoned the idea. :-(